# cohesive.blocks() function in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have been studying igraph package in R. I was not able to understand cohesive.blocks function.  Can somebody help me, please?
I formed an example and got the following output.

```
B-1          c 0, n 405
  '- B-2       c 1, n   8
  '- B-3       c 1, n   2
   '- B-4       c 1, n  26
   '- B-5       c 1, n 268
  '- B-48   c 2, n   4
'- B-49   c 2, n   3
'- B-50   c 2, n   3
```

What does this output mean?

Comment: Please include the `igraph` tag for igraph related questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From http://igraph.org/r/doc/cohesive.blocks.html:

> ```
> Cohesive block structure:
> B-1         c 1, n 23
> '- B-2      c 2, n 14   oooooooo.. .o......oo ooo 
>    '- B-4   c 5, n  7   ooooooo... .......... ... 
> '- B-3      c 2, n 10   ......o.oo o.oooooo.. ... 
>    '- B-5   c 3, n  4   ......o.oo o......... ...
> ```
>
> The left part shows the block structure, in this case for five blocks.
>   The first block always corresponds to the whole graph, even if its
>   cohesion is zero. Then cohesion of the block and the number of
>   vertices in the block are shown. The last part is only printed if the
>   display is wide enough and shows the vertices in the blocks, ordered
>   by vertex ids. ‘o’ means that the vertex is included, a dot means that
>   it is not, and the vertices are shown in groups of ten.

Comment: Cohesion of block? Meaning?

Comment: See J. Moody and D. R. White. Structural cohesion and embeddedness: A hierarchical concept of social groups. American Sociological Review, 68(1):103–127, Feb 2003.